# How to manage video feeds in WIndows 10?

Tags: windows, drivers, video, webcam

I'm attempting to use some software that doesn't allow me to select which video feed it's taking in, so all it's seeing is my blank virtual camera and not my actual webcam. I've tried searching for applications like this, but all that comes up are webcam software or other random results that aren't what I want.

The only solution I can see to my problem is uninstalling my virtual camera and reinstalling it later when I want to use it. It's surprising to me how something like this isn't natively supported by Windows, and it's such a hassle to deal with.

Are there any other solutions to picking and choosing with camera programs default to, or is my only option really to just uninstall and reinstall the next time I want to use my virtual camera feeds?

[Software in question](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gazerecorder/)

Comment: If you tell us what software you are having trouble with then someone might be able to tell you how to set it up.

Comment: Added info, but even besides the specific hardware, the ability to be able to select a default camera would be useful in many programs, even in the basic Windows camera app, which doesn't allow you to select a camera.

Comment: You incorrectly assume the software would respect the default camera.  Which is the reason knowing what the software is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows 11 settings now includes the ability to manage cameras.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-cameras-with-camera-settings-in-windows-11-97997ed5-bb98-47b6-a13d-964106997757) You can view connected cameras, their settings, and previews of the feed. It also claims to include "Windows Studio effects" if you have an NPU.

Comment: A link only answer is not acceptable.  Please edit it to provide the essentials here, maybe screenshots or quotes from the instructions.